# Silverlight WCF throwing The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight

I'm trying to figure why this is happening. Its super weird

Following are the exact calls i have. Whenever i add that extra datameber at the end of vehicles datacontract i get remote server returned an error: NotFound. when calling pick.SaveVehiclesAsync(infoKey, data);

### From Silverlight Side

```
public void SaveVehicles(InfoKey infoKey, ObservableCollection<VehicleFullInfoModel> vehicleFullInfoCollection, EventHandler<SaveVehiclesEventArgs> callBack)
    {
        var pick = new **ProjectServiceClient**();
        pick.SaveVehiclesCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (callBack != null)
                callBack(this, new SaveVehiclesEventArgs(e.Result, e.fault));
        };
        var data =
            new ObservableCollection<VehicleFullInfo>(vehicleFullInfoCollection.Select(rec => rec.Data).ToList());
        pick.SaveVehiclesAsync(infoKey, data);
    }
```

------------- From WCF service

```
public interface IProjectService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SaveVehicles(InfoKey infoKey, IList<VehicleFullInfo> vehicleFullInfoCollection, out FaultContract fault);
}
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ProjectService : IProjectService
{
    public string SaveVehicles(InfoKey infoKey, IList<VehicleFullInfo> vehicleFullInfoCollection, out FaultContract fault)
    {      
        return PickVehicles.SaveVehicles(infoKey, vehicleFullInfoCollection,  out fault);
    }
}
```

--------- PickVehicles Class-------

Do Saving to a file

------------ Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
public class VehicleFullInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; private set; }
}
```

------ Vehicle Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle(Data vehicleData, int index)
    {

    }

    [DataMember]
    public string VehicleNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool? IsVehicleFromPolicy { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool? IsInclude { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string VIN { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public VehicleTypeEnum Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? ModelYear { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public VehicleMake Make { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool? HasAntiTheft { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public AirBagTypeEnum AirBagType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? GarageZip { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public VehicleUseTypeEnum VehicleUseType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? Miles { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? TrailerValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool? IsMotorhomeSold { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? TrailerCamperLength { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TrailerDesc { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? TrailerGrossWeight { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ExtraField { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Not Found` is a generic error on Silverlight which can mean a lot of things - cross-domain issues, any non-200 responses from the network, etc. There are a few things you can do, such as enabling tracing on the server side, or looking at the network traffic with a tool such as Fiddler, which will give you more information about your error.

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2008/04/16/debugging-web-service-usage-in-silverlight-2.aspx has some information which are useful when debugging WCF calls made by Silverlight.

Comment: I ran the tracing i couldn't find any errors. What strange is when i remove that [DataMember] public string ExtraField { get; set; } Everything works but when i have it i get this error. And to make it more weird when i just remove any other field from DataContract i could keep ExtraFeild Looks like its counting how many datamembers there

Comment: Ran again got this

<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.</Message>

Looks like i have to make it bigger. is there way to give it a sliding value?

Comment: On the web.config of your service, change the `maxReceivedMessageSize` property in the binding which you're using to host your service.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this error happens, just right click the ASP.NET IIS server icon that opens every time you run the application near the clock and stop it.

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your binding configuration in the end point of the server config file -  Example:

```
 <endpoint
           address=""
           binding="pollingDuplexHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="multipleMessagesPerPollPollingDuplexHttpBinding"
           contract="DuplexService.IDuplexService">
</endpoint>
```

but of course you'll have to configure a corresponding binding - such as:

```
<bindings>
        <pollingDuplexHttpBinding>
          <binding name="multipleMessagesPerPollPollingDuplexHttpBinding"
                   duplexMode="MultipleMessagesPerPoll"
                   maxOutputDelay="00:00:07"/>
        </pollingDuplexHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[Make sure your wcf has tracing enabled](http://devrecipeshb.blogspot.com/search/label/WCF). 
This is usually what leads me to the problem, and is what did it this time as well.